# Request Contains Invalid Argument when calling signJwt

Tags: google-cloud-platform, impersonation, service-accounts, google-iam, google-cloud-iam

I'm attempting to call Google Cloud's [signJwt](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/create-short-lived-credentials-direct#sa-credentials-jwt) method with Workload Identity Federation with a service account via domain wide delegation. As far as I can tell I'm following Google's instructions exactly but am getting the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

I'm running the following curl command in the Cloud Shell

```
curl -X POST \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" \
    -d @request.json \
    "https://iamcredentials.googleapis.com/v1/projects/-/serviceAccounts/<SA_USERNAME>%40<PROJECT_NAME>.iam.gserviceaccount.com:signJwt"
```

where `request.json` contains the following:

```
{
        "payload": "{\"iss\":\"<SA_USERNAME>@<PROJECT_NAME>.iam.gserviceaccount.com\",\"scope\":\"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly\",\"aud\":\"https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token\",\"exp\":1672868057013,\"iat\":1672868053513,\"sub\":\"<USER_NAME_OF_USER_TO_IMPERSONATE>@<DOMAIN>\"}",
        "delegates": [],
}
```

Why am I getting an invalid argument error?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this in the request body :

```
{
  "delegates": [
    string
  ],
  "payload": string
}
```

As given in the [document](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/reference/credentials/rest/v1/projects.serviceAccounts/signJwt):

> The sequence of service accounts in a delegation chain. Each service
> account must be granted the roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator role
> on its next service account in the chain. The last service account in
> the chain must be granted the roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator
> role on the service account that is specified in the name field of the
> request.

The delegates must have the following format: projects/-/serviceAccounts/{ACCOUNT_EMAIL_OR_UNIQUEID}. The - wildcard character is required; replacing it with a project ID is invalid.

Also there is a [bug](https://b.corp.google.com/issues/142131408) request on it.You can raise a new request if you need it by using the [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers).

Comment: thanks Fariya, I don't have any delegates since I'm not delegating another service account, just a specific user. Given that what should the string be in my delegates array? I'm following these docs (https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/reference/credentials/rest/v1/projects.serviceAccounts/signJwt) and it seems to suggest delegates are only needed when delegating to a service account.

Comment: Did you get any further on this? 

I've got the same problem, not sure what argument is invalid

Comment: Update on comment above ^

I found that the iat and exp seemed to be a problem. The value appears to be in seconds when I assumed it was ms. (?)